# pdf overwrite - how?

Tags: beamer, pdftex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TeXnicCenter on Windows: Building Problems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36919/texniccenter-on-windows-building-problems)

When writing a paper I keep a YAP viewer open and constantly overwrite the contents. I am trying to get the same behaviour for a presentation but the system (beamer/pdflatex within TeXnicCentre running miktex 2.9) won't allow me.

I understand there is a problem with adobe so I installed another pdf viewer (foxit reader) but am still running into the same problem.

So - how to make the system overwrite the pdf in a smooth way?

Thanks!

Comment: If your PDF is open in something like Adobe Reader nothing else can write to it. You need to make sure that you've not left the file open by accident.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Clarification question: does this refer only to Adobe or other programs as well?

Comment: I think this is an MS Windows specific problem as I have never seen this on either linux or OSX (in fact under linux where adobe reader can reload a file simply, I always leave the file open in the viewer and reload it when I have changed something).

Comment: @ArTourter File locking is something that happens with Adobe Reader (amongst other programs) on Windows, but not on Linux or Mac OS X.

Comment: I use SumatraPDF as one of the outstanding Windows/LaTeX PDF viewers with same setup as you have. It works seamlessly with TeXnicCenter.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg I cannot give a general answer (it depends on the program), but Adobe Reader is unusual in locking PDF files.

Comment: @percusse: I installed SumatraPDF and got this error message "error loading "whatever.tex".

Comment: @percusse: I installed SumatraPDF and got this error message "error loading "whatever.tex". What could go wrong? The only thing I changed in TexNic's profile was the path to the compiler. Should I have tinkered with the options too? Thanks!

Comment: @FelixGoldberg: SumatraPDF is not a different *compiler* (that is still going to be `pdflatex`), but a different *PDF viewer*.

Comment: Indeed, as Caramdir commented it's another PDF viewer like Acrobat Reader. So consider it as a duplicate for Yap not pdflatex.

Comment: @percusse: Thanks, now it works like a charm!! So much easier to work now.

Comment: @percusse: Can you write an answer?

Comment: @FelixGoldberg Do you mind if we close this question as a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36919/3235