# My pdf closes every time in WinEdt

Tags: kile, winedt

I use Kile on Linux and WinEdt on Windows both with same version of MiKTeX. While using KILE, when I compile "PDFLaTeX" , it updates my opend output `pdf` file and does not close the file. Where as in WinEdt it closes the already opened output `pdf` file and open it again after compiling. What irriatates me is while it opens the new output and it goes to first page rather than the page (of output pdf file) I edited. :(

Any remedy would be appreciated.

Comment: The adobe reader locks the pdf. If winedt wouldn't close it, pdflatex couldn't create a new pdf. If you don't like this you will have to use another pdf reader.

Comment: such as `sumatrapdf`

Comment: possible duplicate of [TeXnicCenter on Windows: Building Problems](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36919/texniccenter-on-windows-building-problems)

Comment: I've reviewed a close vote for this, and said to keep open: the phenomenon is clearly the same, but the symptoms seen by the user are different - as a problem-solving Q&A site, we need to keep these questions separate to help people find solutions.

Comment: @Ulrike: Learn to live with it or change your reader would be a good answer - could you post one?  It would be good to link to the qn that egreg linked to.

Answer (score 2):

The adobe reader locks the pdf. If winedt wouldn't close it, pdflatex couldn't create a new pdf. If you don't like this you will have to use another pdf reader.